# How to unit test with go-git

Tags: go, go-git

How do I write a unit test for my code that clones a repo using git-go

Below is a sample of the function I have created. I am cloning multiple repos and reading a particular file that is in that repo, I am unsure how to unit test this function.

```
func cloneRepository(repository string) (repo beans.Repo) {

    dir, err := os.MkdirTemp("./", "temp") //To create a temp folder to clone repo in
    if err != nil...
    
    _, err := git.PlainClone(dir, false, &git.CloneOptions{
               URL: repository,
               Depth: 1,
              })

    var repo beans.Repo
    if err = util.ParseYmlFile("filename.yml", &repo) // Custom util function to parse a file in the repository

    if err = os.RemoveAll(dir); err != nil{...}

   return repo

}
```

Comment: Take a look at the FS abstraction, part of go git repo itself - https://github.com/go-git/go-billy, tests in the go-git repo use the former for abstraction - https://github.com/go-git/go-git/blob/master/example_test.go

Answer (score 3):

You can mock the `git.PlainClone()` function so it returns a custom file for your tests.

Take a look into [spf13's lib](https://github.com/spf13/afero), that provides a filesystem mocking solution!

Answer (score 0):

What we did in the past was create a bare git repository with some predefined content, put it under e.g. `testdata/myrepo.git` and use it during unit-testing.

Commit the repo normally as part of your project.

Comment: Hmm, won't this defeat the purpose of unit-testing? I was under the assumption that unit tests should not hit any "live" external dependencies

Comment: It's not an external dependency, just store it together with your code. Yes you're going to be exercising go-kit code as part of your unit test. That's actually an advantage, since you depend on that code anyway, so it's good to include it.